# Is Angular2 compatible to run on Adobe AIR HTML Browser

Tags: apache-flex, angular, air

I am working on a desktop application which is built using Adobe AIR 19.0,

I need to load a web application (built with angular2-rc.4.0) in HTML control of AIR window

While loading the application I am getting below error and page load does not complete:

`SyntaxError: Parse error
http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1469092721211 : 648
SyntaxError: Parse error
http://localhost:5555/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js?1469092721211 : 242
SyntaxError: Parse error
http://localhost:5555/index.html : 89`

User Agent of AIR browser is : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/19.0

Any help in this regard will help, as I am newbie to Angualr2. However, angular2 application is working correctly on all browser except IE 9 or below.

Comment: have you checked what's at that line in those files?

Comment: I have tried to look into the file, but could not found anything which may causing this. I am unable to debug app in this mode. however, below are the codes that I can locate in respective files :   **Rx.js** `if (typeof Symbol.for === 'function') {` **zone.js** : `ZoneAwarePromise.prototype.catch = function (onRejected) {`